# MDB how to get connection settings from server environment

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, glassfish-3, message-driven-bean

I have a message driven bean which connects to a remote HornetQ JMS provider (different for production/testing).

The connection settings are stored either in sun-ejb-jar.xml or as @ActivationConfigProperty annotations directly in the MDB class.

Since all these settings are bundled with the ear file it makes the deployment process quite cumbersome when you want to test in different environments since you have to remember to change the settings all the time.

Do you have any ideas on how I could make my application read this settings from the server?

I thought of creating some custom resources and read them with @Resource, but I don't know how to make the MDB read those settings because the @Resource injection AFAIK takes place after the MDB is already initilized...

**EDIT**

To clarify:  What I'm looking for is something like sun-ejb-jar.xml configuration file which I should install on each server with specific configuration (for ex, different JMS providers - topics/queues, etc). But my ear app should be unchanged. It should automatically load the enviroment from each server. Does it make sense?

Answer (score 0):

*Do you have any ideas on how I could make my application read this settings from the server?*

JMX-Mbeans can be used to connect with the server. Below is the sample code to connect with the server & fetch information from it, may help you to get idea of it.

```
//---

    Hashtable props = new Hashtable();
    props.put(InitialContext.PROVIDER_URL, "jnp://localhost:1099");
    props.put(InitialContext.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContextFactory");

    InitialContext ctx = new InitialContext(props);

    MBeanServerConnection serverConn = (MBeanServerConnection)ctx.lookup("jmx/rmi/RMIAdaptor");

    Set<Object> listOfBeans =  serverConn.queryMBeans(null, null); // find-all

    for(Object o : listOfBeans){

        ObjectInstance beanInfo = (ObjectInstance) o;
        System.out.println(beanInfo.getObjectName());
    }

//---
```

It outputs the registered topics/queues like `jboss.mq.destination:service=Topic,name=ProvisioningResponseTopic` along with other stuff.

MBeans can also be used to get other information like ports, binding-address, domain etc.

**Note : The above code is JBoss specific, but same can be achieved for Glassfish.**

I don't know much about Glassfish. I think there is Application Server Management eXtension (AMX) to accomplish it.

Comment: Hi and thanks for the input. I probably wasn't very clear in my question, see my edited post.

Comment: I think you want to read configuration from the server without reading xml files. If that so, then I have pointed same topic to connect to specific server & get configuration information from it dynamically. Point out if I haven't understood correctly.